# How to prove that this polynomial inequality region is connected?

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness, complex-dynamics

I understand that proof that the Mandelbrot Set is connected is not easy to follow and requires mathematical tools an Engineer probably doesn't have.  But I got to wondering if there was a more accessible proof of the softer assertion, that the region $ |z_n(c)| < 2 $ is connected, where $z_n = z_{n-1}^2 + c$ and $ z_0 = c $.  Then one just needs to accept that this holds in the n -> Infinity case.

Is there such a proof?

I found this old discussion, and someone suggested exactly what I thought of, but they didn't show HOW to prove that.

[Interesting but elementary properties of the Mandelbrot Set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67239/interesting-but-elementary-properties-of-the-mandelbrot-set)